# Import a .jar (vaadin-6.4.8.jar) file in a Clojure (.clj) script

Tags: clojure, vaadin

I need to write a Clojure script to create a simple app by using Vaadin.
In Java I cam use some thing like this. 
 "import com.vaadin.Application;" 
But I don't know how to do it in Clojure. 
I need to know how to import it and the place I should keep that .jar.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a build tool for clojure called leiningen.

- Follow these instructions to install it: https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen
- Create a new project
- Put that jar to lib folder
- Import classes you need

For example:

```
(ns your-project-name.core
  (:import (com.vaadin Application)
           (com.vaadin.ui Button Form HorizontalLayout)
           (com.vaadin.data.Property ValueChangeEvent)))
```

Also read this article on how to use java classes in clojure: http://java.ociweb.com/mark/clojure/article.html#JavaInterop

---

Note that clojure does not provide a way to import every class in a Java package without specifying each class explicitly: [How do I import the entire package but exclude some in Clojure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207095/how-do-i-import-the-entire-package-but-exclude-some-in-clojure)

Answer (score 1):

I use Vaadin with Clojure as well and I initially had alot of pain. In the end I made sure I wrote alot of example Vaadin applications using Java only. Once I was familiar with Vaadin I wrote alot of example Clojure applications. Once I was proficient in both then I attempted to use Vaadin with Clojure, and I haven't looked back since.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot publish the examples made for Clojure and Vaadin together as they are private code owned by my employer, but for Java and Clojure I used publicly available tutorials. However I would recommend the following place to get started: http://dev.vaadin.com/wiki/Articles/ClojureScripting

Comment: Dear Zubair, What is the file structure and what are the things in project.clj. I am not very good in clojure. How to create that structure with "lein" command. Or there is another way...?? Thank you.

Comment: Yaa dude.. It's working fine. You are correct, that i should know clojure and vaadin well to do this. Thanks a lot. Keep it up bro.