# importing lucene jars in clojure

Tags: java, clojure, lucene, leiningen

I try to import two `org.apache.lucene` jars in `lein` project and get a `ClassNotFoundException`.

Here is my `project.clj` file:

```
(defproject clj_processing_tweets "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"]
                 [org.apache.lucene/lucene-core "4.10.3"]
                 [org.apache.lucene/lucene-analyzers-common "4.10.3"]]
  :profiles {:dev {:dependencies [[speclj "3.1.0"]]}}
  :plugins [[speclj "3.1.0"]]
  :test-paths ["spec"])
```

After running `lein deps` I send `core.clj` to the lein repl and I got

```
CompilerException java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.lucene.analysis.*, compiling:(clj_processing_tweets/core.
clj:1:36)
```

Here is my `core.clj` file:

```
(ns clj_processing_tweets.core
  (:import [org.apache.lucene.analysis *]))
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to import each class you want to use separately, as clojure doesn't allow you to specify a wildcard on Java import.

See this answer to a more general question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1213628/66722

So, for example:

```
(ns clj_processing_tweets.core
  (:import [org.apache.lucene.analysis Analyzer Tokenizer]))
```